# C++ pure virtual error

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to inherit from an abstract class but getting the following errors:

> In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/vector:64:0,
>                    from /usr/include/boost/format.hpp:17,
>                    from /usr/include/boost/math/policies/error_handling.hpp:31,
>                    from /usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp:14,
>                    from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/time.h:58,
>                    from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/ros.h:38,
>                    from /home/gil/catkin_ws/src/manager/include/Tasks/Task.h:4,
>                    from /home/gil/catkin_ws/src/manager/src/Tasks/Task.cpp:1:
>   /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:713:7: error: invalid abstract
>   parameter type ‘manager::Task’
>          resize(size_type __new_size, value_type __x = value_type())

--

> /home/gil/catkin_ws/src/manager/include/Tasks/Task.h:11:16: note:
>   virtual void manager::Task::Execute()    virtual void Execute() = 0;
>                   ^ In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/vector:64:0,
>                    from /usr/include/boost/format.hpp:17,
>                    from /usr/include/boost/math/policies/error_handling.hpp:31,
>                    from /usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp:14,
>                    from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/time.h:58,
>                    from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/ros.h:38,
>                    from /home/gil/catkin_ws/src/manager/include/Tasks/Task.h:4,
>                    from /home/gil/catkin_ws/src/manager/include/Tasks/RootTask.h:10,
>                    from /home/gil/catkin_ws/src/manager/src/Tasks/RootTask.cpp:8:
>   /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:713:7: error: invalid abstract
>   parameter type ‘manager::Task’
>          resize(size_type __new_size, value_type __x = value_type())

--

> manager/CMakeFiles/manager.dir/build.make:110: recipe for target
>   'manager/CMakeFiles/manager.dir/src/Tasks/Task.cpp.o' failed make[2]:
>   *** [manager/CMakeFiles/manager.dir/src/Tasks/Task.cpp.o] Error 1 make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
>   manager/CMakeFiles/manager.dir/build.make:158: recipe for target
>   'manager/CMakeFiles/manager.dir/src/Tasks/RootTask.cpp.o' failed
>   make[2]: *** [manager/CMakeFiles/manager.dir/src/Tasks/RootTask.cpp.o]
>   Error 1 In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/vector:64:0,
>                    from /usr/include/boost/format.hpp:17,
>                    from /usr/include/boost/math/policies/error_handling.hpp:31,
>                    from /usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp:14,
>                    from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/time.h:58,
>                    from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/ros.h:38,
>                    from /home/gil/catkin_ws/src/manager/src/indoor_mission_action_server.cpp:9:
>   /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:713:7: error: invalid abstract
>   parameter type ‘manager::Task’
>          resize(size_type __new_size, value_type __x = value_type())

Not sure what am i missing...
Here are my H and CPP files:

RootTask.cpp

```
#include "Tasks/RootTask.h"
namespace manager {
  RootTask::RootTask(std::string name) {
    mTaskName = name;
  }
  RootTask::~RootTask() {}
  RootTask::RootTask() {}

  void RootTask::Execute() {}

  void RootTask::setTaskSeqByName() {}
  std::string RootTask::GetTaskName() {
    return mTaskName;
  }
}
```

RootTask.h

```
#include "Tasks/Task.h"
namespace manager {
  class RootTask: public Task {
    public:

      RootTask();
    RootTask(std::string name);~RootTask();

    void Execute();
    void setTaskSeqByName();
    std::string GetTaskName();
  };
}
```

Task.cpp

```
#include "Tasks/Task.h"
#include < iostream >

  namespace manager {
    void Task::Stop() {}
    void Task::Pause() {}
    void Task::OnError() {}
    std::string Task::GetTaskName() {}
    void Task::setTaskSeqByName() {}
  }
```

Task.h

```
#pragma once

#include < iostream > 
#include "ros/ros.h"

namespace manager {
  class Task {
    public:
      virtual void Execute() = 0;
    virtual void setTaskSeqByName();
    virtual void Stop();
    virtual void Pause();
    virtual void OnError();
    virtual std::string GetTaskName();

    protected:
      std::string mTaskName;
    std::vector < Task > mTaskSequence;
  };
}
```

Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 3):

In `Task` you have a member

```
std::vector < Task > mTaskSequence;
```

You cannot have this as `Task` is an abstract class and you cannot make an instance of it.  You need to use a pointer type like

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Task>> mTaskSequence;
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @NathanOliver points out how you can fix the compiler error.

I want to point out that having a `Task` contain list  of pointers to other `Task`s seems to be a possible design flaw.

You may want to consider moving it up to a higher level class that deals with sequences of `Task`s.

Comment: hmmm i see what you are saying.... trying to figure out a way to workaround it...